# MySQL Update with same naming pattern

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column called EmpNumber in TableA.  I have a series of records where EmpNumber column starts with CC.  For example:  CC21, CC33, CC43 etc.

I'd like to append every EmpNumber that starts with CC with an a at the end of the value.

CC21 would be CC21a, CC33 would be CC33a, CC41 would be CC41a

I can manually do this by specifying the initial value and what I want changed but I am looking at a few hundred changes do it manually.

Is there a way to do this with a single query for all records starting with CC?

Comment: The question title confuses me - what are the 3 tables? You only mention one column, I assume to be in one table.

Comment: I've updated it, it is inaccurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `left()` function and a case in update

```
update table
set EmpNumber = case when left(EmpNumber,2) = 'CC'
  then concat(EmpNumber,'a')
  else EmpNumber end
```

`left(EmpNumber,2)` will pick starting 2 characters from the column like `left('test',2)` will result 'te' so compare the result of left function in case and if equals to 'CC' then concat your column with your desired character

Edit as **Michael Berkowski** suggested yes you can use simple where

```
update table
set EmpNumber =  concat(EmpNumber,'a')
where left(EmpNumber,2) = 'CC'
```

Comment: Alternatively the `LEFT(EmpNumber, 2) = 'CC'` can go in the `WHERE` clause instead of a `CASE`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes this is better than mine approach thanks

Answer (score 1):

hmm, if i get your question right:

```
UPDATE table SET EmpNumber = CONCAT(EmpNumber, 'a') WHERE EmpNumber LIKE 'CC%'
```

Comment: To me, the much clearer and more straightforward of the two answers given thus far.